# Android размер изображения -1

Tags: android, imageview

Добрый день, для масштабирования изображения получаю его отношение сторон таким образом:

```
   BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;  
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);  
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;  
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;
```

photoW и photoH принимают значения -1.

Далее изображение загружается в ImageView следующим образом:

```
File imagePath = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);  
Picasso.with(context)  
    .load(imagePath)  
    .resize(newXSize,newYSize)  
    .into(imageView);
```

Загрузка происходит без ошибок, но изображение отсутствует.

Самое странное в том, что на других четырех устройствах все работает нормально и на эмуляторе тоже, разрешение на чтение и запись в файл есть. Работает на android 4.4.2, 6.0.1, 7.0, но не работает на 6.0) В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может быть `decodeFile` асинхронный? Выведите значения `outWidth` и `outHeight` до декодинга, чему они равны?

Comment: На других устройствах с указанными версиями все работает, тут даже изображение не подгружается в  ImageView. Может они в 6.0 намудрили с разрешениями?

Comment: Разрешение на интернет считается неопасным и не сильно требующем, поэтому получать их в рантайме не надо

Comment: Прошу прощения, не понял при чем тут разрешение на интернет.

Comment: А про какие разрешения вы говорите?

Comment: Я про разрешения на доступ к камере, чтению и запись в память.

Comment: Заметил, что только на этом устройстве включено шифрование, после хард резета шифрование осталось. Может это связано с шифрованием, т.к. BitmapFactory.decodeFile декодирует изображение с камеры?

Comment: Что-то с этим 100% связано

Comment: Проблема решена. Высота и ширина отрабатываются нормально, если сохранять изображение с камеры не в галерею, а свою папку (проблема воспроизводилась только на одном устройстве). Picasso пришлось заменить на Universal Image Loader, нормального объяснения причины не нашел, но пару раз на англоязычных сайтах видел, что Picasso совместим не со всеми устройствами.